# Feature Class to Feature Class error: 999999 (ArcGIS Pro 2.5)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-999999, arcgis-notebook

I've tried this with the new ArcGIS Pro 2.5 Python Notebook and the Python compiler from within Pro.

I have about 15 layers that I'm reading in from a couple different external servers. I can read in test layers from all unique servers just fine, but there are three layers that after I read them into my table of contents, they fail when using the Feature Class to Feature Class GP tool.

Error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
ERROR: code:500, Error performing query operation, Internal server error.
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

What I have in Notebook and what I've tried in the compiler:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Project\Pro_Points2018.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]

env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Project\Pro_Points.gdb"
out_loc = r"C:\Project\Pro_Points.gdb"

mapx.addDataFromPath(r"https://gisportal.hrsa.gov/server/rest/services/Shortage/MedicallyUnderservedAreas_FS/FeatureServer/0")

arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass("Medically Underserved Areas /Populations – perimeter polygons", out_loc, "MUA_SHP_DET_CUR_VX", '')
```

Other posts point to the error being caused by import/export name being the same, but I've already verified that.

All I'm trying to do is read a FC in from someone's server (that I have access to), and save it off locally in my GDB.

Comment: Have you read the description in the [Metadata](https://gisportal.hrsa.gov/server/rest/services/Shortage/MedicallyUnderservedAreas_FS/FeatureServer/0) for the Feature Service layer...?

Comment: I don't think you can use a feature service as the input to `FeatureClassToFeatureClass()`.  If I try it in the GUI it won't even let me add such a layer as the input to the tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd yes, but I've been able to do the same with other feature services from the same source that have the same metadata note. Perhaps the restriction is only enforced on the three I'm trying to use.